# tao_idl returns with unspecified error when compiling using gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, corba, idl, ace

Hi I'm quite new to ACE ORB(TAO). My exisiting system compiles fine with **xcc** compiler in solaris. Now I got to use **gcc** compiler instead. When I try to compile my source code using gcc, I get the following error

`/sbcimp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/bin/tao_idl: preprocessor "CC" returned with an error
xmake: /sbcimp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/bin/tao_idl: error 1 (0x1)`

Why does tao_idl return this error? All I know is tao_idl compiles idl sources for ACE ORB. This error doesn't provide me any other clue regarding the reason behind this error.. Where can I find further details about this error?

I dont see much help in the net for tao_idl compiling. Can someone shed some light on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Johnny Willemsen's answer, I thoguht of adding a bit of more details so that it would be helpful for someone. 
TAO_IDL uses an external pre processor.

1. If the macro TAO_IDL_PREPROCESSOR is defined, then it will use that.
2. Else if the macro ACE_CC_PREPROCESSOR is defined, then it will use that.
3. Otherwise, it will use "cc"

The problem that I had was that I was trying to use g++ as the precompiler, without setting any of the above macros. Hence TAO_IDL was always looking for cc.

Solution: 
export TAO_IDL_PREPROCESSOR=/rtcigp/run/pd/gcc/32-bit/4.4.1/bin/g++

then include g++ binary into PATH
`export PATH="$PATH:/rtcigp/run/pd/gcc/32-bit/4.4.1/bin"`

This makes g++ as the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

TAO_IDL uses CC as preprocessor, do you have that available in your PATH when invoking TAO_IDL, just try to execute CC directly from the commandline.

Comment: I have cc (solaris C compiler in my machine)
Are you saying tao_idl needs CC as preprocessor by looking at this error?

I thought `CC` in the error message points to a variable in my xmake file


`CC =        $(TOOLSBIN)xcc -c $(INC) -I$(SRC)`

Comment: It could be that the compiler flags for xcc and gcc are different and that it causes the problem. Have you compiled the full tree with gcc? Maybe try to run TAO_IDL manually and pass -Ucc to get the cc preprocessor?